# submiting form using a button outside the form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

iam not an expert in coding but just a learner
i have created  a dynamic form. when the form is generated, the user is expected to fill and submit
the form details directly to google sheet.
ref https://trickuweb.com/submit-custom-html-form-data-to-google-sheets.php
[enter link description here][1]
[1]: https://trickuweb.com/submit-custom-html-form-data-to-google-sheets.php
this is the html

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>my project</title>
<link href="" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<style>
p{
color: blue;
font-size: 20px;
}

button{
color: blue;
max-width: 200px;
height: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>
</body>
<p>Fill the form below to submit to google sheet</p>
<div id ='share' style='width: 200px; height: 450px; border: 2px solid blue;' >
</div>

<div class="controls">
<button id='submit'>FORM SUBMIT</button> <br>

</div>


<!-- to access jquery-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is the jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var formData =
["Name","Email","Phone"];

function createForm2(){
    $("#share").append('<form name="google-sheet">');
    for(var f=1; f<4; f++){
 
   $("#share form").append('<br><label>'+ f +'</label><input type="text" placeholder='+ formData[f-1] + '  name=' + formData[f-1] +  '  id=""/>');
   }
   $("#share form").append('<br><input type="submit" id="savebutton" value="Save" />');


    const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwOE4ndEngGXcIerdQ708EUI0O1qdjJ7T2YTpGmzJYe_0VL3m4YlPzt9zrMl8oSewqG-Q/exec'
            const form = document.forms['google-sheet']
          
            form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
              //e.preventDefault()
              fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
                .then(response => alert("Thanks for Contacting us..! We Will Contact You Soon..."))
                //.catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
                .catch(error => alert("An error occured while processing your request"))
            })
            
        $("#ok").on("click",function(){form.submit(); });
}

});
```

if i click on the save button inside the form it works fine but if i click on the form submit button the data is not submitted?
help!

Comment: Where's the button outside the form ? Where is the button with the id="ok" ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use "form" attribute if you want to submit form using a button outside form

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes_form.asp

Example:

```
<form id="Form1" method="POST" action="something.php">
    <input type="text" name="name">
</form>

<input type="submit" form="Form1">
```

Comment: 'krelq thank you so much for. your contribution. your method only worked for mannualy created forms and not dynamically created form unles i had to adjust my code. ifinally found a solution here [link] (Submit form using a button outside the <form> tag)